# Divide many cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a simple diagram with percentage values on the x-axis `0.1 - 1.0` and a number of leafs on the y-axis for each such percentage. The values I am inserting to the y-axis (No. Leafs) are the total number, but I am only interested in the average number.

So, my question is: What can I do to tell many cells that each of them should divide the inserted value by a number? Is there any way to use something like a `this` to self-reference the cell? I do not want to go for `=(cell/50)` for each cell individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your dividing as a one-time activity; you can easily do it like this:

1. type the divisor in any empty cell, and copy it (CTRL+C)
2. select all cells you want divided
3. use 'Paste Special' (not Paste!),
4. in the dialog that comes up, choose 'Values' and 'Divide'. Hit Ok.

All the values will be divided and replaced by the result. Remove the Divisor from the extra cell, and you are done.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!